# Dependant destroy generates wrong sql query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have m:n association with counter cache. I want delete user and remove appropriate records from the users_items association. The sql query which should remove records from users_items association is wrong.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users_items, class_name: 'UsersItem', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, through: :users_items
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users_items, class_name: 'UsersItem', dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :users_items
end

class UsersItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :item, counter_cache: true
end

u = User.last
u.destroy

 (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  UsersItem Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users_items".* FROM "users_items" WHERE   "users_items"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 41]]
  UsersItem Destroy (1.9ms)  DELETE FROM "users_items" WHERE "users_items"."" IS NULL
 (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK

 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near """")
 LINE 1: DELETE FROM "users_items" WHERE "users_items"."" IS NULL
```

Comment: Can you try setting `foreign_key` explicitly for `users_items` association?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the users_items table. The table was created without primary key. It started working when I added the primary id.

Myth